# Types lost after mixin?

Tags: typescript, mixins

I followed these [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) and set up a mixin class:

```
class ClassA {
    firstName(): string {
        return "James";
    }
}
class ClassB {
    lastName(): string {
        return "Bond";
    }
}

class Mixin {} // <--

interface Mixin extends ClassA, ClassB {}

function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name));
        });
    });
}

applyMixins(Mixin, [ClassA, ClassB])

for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ClassA.prototype)) {
    const method = ClassA.prototype[name];
    if (typeof method === "function") {
        Mixin.prototype[name] = ClassA.prototype[name];
    }
}
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ClassB.prototype)) {
    const method = ClassB.prototype[name];
    if (typeof method === "function") {
        Mixin.prototype[name] = ClassB.prototype[name];
    }
}
const mixin = new Mixin();
console.log("Mixin contains: " + mixin.firstName() + " and " + mixin.lastName());
const asClassA = mixin as ClassA;
console.log(asClassA);
const asClassB = mixin as ClassB;
console.log(asClassB);

const isIstanceOfA = (mixin instanceof ClassA);
console.log(isIstanceOfA);
const isIstanceOfB = (mixin instanceof ClassB);
console.log(isIstanceOfB);
```

When using the mixinclass I cannot cast it to `ClassA`/`ClassB` properly. And with `instanceOf` - I get false.

Are the original types lost with the mixin class - or have have I missed something?

it prints:

> Mixin contains: James and Bond
>
> ClassB {}
>
> ClassB {}
>
> false
>
> false

to the console.

---

I found another [typescript doc example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html). And another example [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/mixin-classes-in-typescript). [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743). But running them with ts-node I get:

> ReferenceError: __extends is not defined

```
function Tagged<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base { // <-- error thrown here
        _tag: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._tag = "";
        }
    }
}
```

It works running it NativeScript though - where my original intention of using it was.

Comment: Can you provide a codesanbox?

Comment: @JohnnyZabala the current code can be pasted into a ts file and ran with ts-node

Comment: I found this extensive article: https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know/